# Efficient way to read a compressed gz file (heavy file) in C++

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++. I'm trying to process a gz file and it seems to be taking almost 2 hrs to do the processing. Is there an efficient way to process it. Something faster.

The file is 8GB. This code seems to work fine but it is taking way lot of time. any easy efficient method???

I'm writing the 2 chunks of data together so that there is no data lost. I tried gzseek, and it seemed to be very cumbersome. so just reading the entire data twice.

Can anybody suggest a simpler method or the right method to do this?

```
     FILE *out;
        gzFile f = gzopen("list.gz","rb");
        out = fopen("output.txt", "ab");
        while(1)
        {
            int err;
            unsigned char buffer[1001];
            int bytes_read = gzread (f, buffer, 1001); 
            fwrite(buffer,sizeof(unsigned char),sizeof(buffer),out);


            std::ifstream fin("output.txt");
            string read_line;
            while (getline(fin, read_line))
            {
                /* Do something */
            }
                remove("output.txt");
                fwrite(buffer,sizeof(unsigned char),sizeof(buffer),out);

                if (bytes_read < 1000) {
                    if (gzeof (f)) {
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        const char * error_string;
                        error_string = gzerror (f, & err);
                        if (err) {
                            fprintf (stderr, "Error: %s.\n", error_string);
                            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
                        }
                    }

            }
            fclose(out);
            gzclose (f);
```

Answer (score 2):

You do this about once per kilobyte of uncompressed data:

```
out = fopen("output.txt", "ab");
fwrite(buffer,sizeof(unsigned char),sizeof(buffer),out);
fclose(out);
```

Opening and closing a file is incredibly expensive.  Hoist the open and close out of the loop.

You also do this once per kilobyte of compressed data:

```
std::ifstream fin("output.txt");
string read_line;
while (getline(fin, read_line)) { ... }
```

And you do this once per **line**:

```
remove("output.txt");
out = fopen("output.txt", "ab");
fwrite(buffer,sizeof(unsigned char),sizeof(buffer),out);
fclose(out);
```

And then you close the file in the middle of the loop.

Comment: I'm adding it twice so that no data is lost in the continuation. If i read the first 1KB data and store it in a file and process it then in the next 1KB data , just half the line will be copied. To overcome that, I'm copying it twice

Comment: Is there a simpler way to avoid redundancy and also not lose any data??

Comment: I want to read the gzipped file. So I thought the best way was to read it in chunks and process it. May I know what am i doing wrong?? I'm pretty new to C++

Comment: I have edited my program. May be it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

If you have sufficient virtual memory available, the most efficient way to read a file on most systems is to map the file to memory and let the operating system's paging handle the reads.

The process for doing this is system dependent.